# LeanTween animation not working in Android (was working before) but it's working well on iOS and Unity Editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, leantween

LeanTween animation not working on the Android build. The animations were working well before the new APK 33 Google update requirement.

However, it's working well in iOS and the Editor perfectly.

Tried checking logs, and nothing shows up as a problem as it works well on the Unity Editor.